# getting duplicated results from nested foreach loop

Tags: php, html, mysql, loops, pdo

I'm trying to get the following output from mysql for [Google Line Chart API:](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart?hl=zh-tw#Example)

```
[["product","diameter","width"],["Product 1","2","4"],["Product 2","4","8"]]
```

I have set up several input checkboxes to send field names (e.g width,diameter) to the database via `$_POST["info"]` and retrieve the values from those fields.  Here's the part that generates the data from mysql:

```
$result = $users->fetchAll();
$comma = "";
$data="";
$data[0] = array_merge(array(product),$info);   
$i = 1;
foreach ($result as $r)
{
    foreach($_POST["info"] as $p)
    {    
        $d .= $comma.$r[$p];     // trying to get "$r["width"],$r["diameter"]"            
    }
    $comma = ",";
    $data[$i] = array($r["name"], $d);
    $i++;
}   
echo json_encode($data);
```

My desired output should be like this:

```
[["product","diameter","width"],["Product 1","2","4"],["Product 2","4","8"]]
```

But that code is generating duplicated results like this

```
[["product","diameter","width"],["Product 1","24"],["Product 2","24,4,8"]]
```

I guess I shouldn't be using the nested foreach to loop over `$_POST`. Can anyone tell me how to fix that?

Full PHP Code:

```
$info = $_POST["info"]; // It contains an array with values like width,diameter,thickness etc...
$comma = "";
foreach($info as $in)
{ 
    $field .= "".$comma."b.".$in."";
    $comma = ",";
}

$sql = "
        SELECT {$field},a.user_id,a.name
        FROM `product_detail` a INNER JOIN
        `attr` b ON a.model = b.model 
        WHERE a.user_id = ?
        GROUP BY a.model
       ";
$users = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$users->bindValue(1, $_SESSION["user_id"]);  
$users->execute();
$result = $users->fetchAll();
$comma = "";
$data="";
$i = 1;
$data[0] = array_merge(array(product),$info);       
foreach ($result as $r)
{
    foreach($_POST["info"] as $p)
    {    
        $d .= $comma.$r[$p];                
    }
    $comma = ",";
    $data[$i] = array($r["name"], $d);
    $i++;
}   
echo json_encode($data);
```

$_POST["info"] Content:

```
Array
(
    [0] => diameter
    [1] => width
)
```

Comment: Please post the content of `$_POST["info"];` and `$result` - otherwise it's hard to predict what's going on.

Comment: @Hirnhamster, sorry, please wait, someone has edited out my $POST content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it like this:

```
$result = $users->fetchAll();
$data="";
$data[0] = array_merge(array(product),$info);   
$i = 1;
foreach ($result as $r)
{
    $d[]=$r["name"];
    foreach($_POST["info"] as $p)
    {    
        $d[]= $r[$p];
    }
    $data[$i] = $d;
    $d=array(); //set $d to empty not to get duplicate results
    $i++;
}   
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: your solution seems to be closer, but the output is missing double quotes separating the values between diameter and width: `[["product","diameter","width"],["Product 1","2,4"],["Product 2","4,8"]]`

Comment: CodeBird, It works. I use `echo json_encode($data,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK)` at the end because I just found out the API doesn't allow the number wrapped in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

The end result you are looking for, is valid JSON. You should not try to manually generate that.

Instead you should make an array of arrays in php and use `json_encode($array)` to get the result you are looking for.

Also note that by injecting your POST variables directly in your query, you are vulnerable to sql injection. When accepting fields, you should check them against a white-list of allowed values.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below solution:

```
$result = $users->fetchAll();
$data="";
$data[0] = array_merge(array(product),$info);   
$i = 1;
foreach ($result as $r)
{
    $d = array();
    foreach($_POST["info"] as $p)
    {    
        $d[] = $r[$p];     // trying to get "$r["width"],$r["diameter"]"            
    }
    $data[$i] = array($r["name"]) +$d;
    $i++;
}   
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: I just tested your solution. It can only get the values from the width field, like this: `[["product","diameter","width"],["Product 1","4"],["Product 2","8"]]`

Comment: after creating your query try to output it to the screen and then run it in MySql client use `var_dump($sql);` and make sure it has both `width` and `diameter`